# Simplest maven module, that just archives the source directory

Tags: maven

I have fairly complicated Maven project with multiple submodules.  Recently I got a need to have another submodule that will contain some maintenance / deployment scripts.  The reason for having it as another maven submodule is because my build script takes of version stamping and packaging up the complete distribution.

For some reason I can't find the existing maven archetype that just zips up the source directory and puts it into the 'target' folder.   Can someone point me to the correct archetype I should use.  Or probably this could be done by writing a simple pom file.  Perhaps maven-archvie-plugin could do the trick,  but I have no idea how to set it up so it archives during the 'package' phase of the build and puts the output to the correct location.  Despite writing a large build script, my maven mojo is still very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [maven-sources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) which is exactly intended for that purpose. But usually if you do a mvn release the sources artifact will be generated as well. Of course you can use the maven-assembly-plugin for that purpose as wel.
Based on your description i would suggest to have a separate maven-module which consists of the scripts in src/main/resources and the filtering should be activated to put the version information into the scripts. Within that module you can use the maven-sources-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways of doing this:

- Keep the scripts in `src/main/resources` and use the generated jar file (if your project has *packaging* of type *jar*). The jar file essentially is a zip file, which will be generated in the *target* directory. It will also be versionized, deployed, etc. once you create a release. That's probably the easiest solution.
- If you want a *zip* file (or *tar.gz* or similar), use the Maven Assembly Plugin to create an assembly, which will give you more fine-grained control over the generated archive and its contents. Please see the examples on the plugin's page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/